# OpenLDAP and range attributes

Tags: openldap, query, attributes

I am trying to query the "member" attribute of a groupOfNames object, and in AD, I can be sure to retrieve all of them, should they exceed the maximum of 1000 entries, by using ranged attribute queries. They look like this:

```
member;range=0-999
```

This seems not to work in OpenLDAP, I get no member attributes back at all. What is the alternative, if there is one?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it seems that the attribute range extension is a proprietary Microsoft invention that is not implemented in OpenLDAP as it is not officially supported or backed by RFCs.